# Visualisation problem in the command-line

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I have an Ubuntu 18.04. I can't write well in the command-line. Sometimes it is possible to write the first command but nextly I can't see the result. It's easy to see in the image.

[image]

What I have done in this image is typing :

```
$ cd nek5_svn
$ cd trunk
```

As you can see, the command-line does answer at what I want but I can not see what is doing. This has happen from one day to another.

Does anyone know what can I do?

Thank you so much.

Eva.

Comment: Welcome! Did you change your `.bashrc`?

Comment: No, I haven't changed anything